# Есть ли способ настроить light theme в codewars? Черный мод вредит моим глазам изза экрана

Tags: c++, алгоритм

у меня экран плохо отображает черный цвет с белыми буквами. Изза чего глаза очень напрягаются, но сайт очень нравится, практикуюсь целый день. Решил все задачи на ХаккерРанк теперь перешел на Кодварс, но тут такое... Нашел один сайт, автор предлагает один способ, он делается добавлением расширения в браузер, но почему то не работает. Ссылку преложить не смогу, иначе вопрос заблокируют.

Comment: данный вопрос не относится к тематике сайта, программированию и с++ в частности

Comment: Я уже нашел кстати. Но насчет пользы я бы поспорил. Данный сайт относиться напрямую к программированию. Я столкнулся с проблемой, которая доставляет мне хлопот не меньше чем ошибка в коде. И в общем, я отвечу сам на свой же вопрос, на форумах есть немало людей ищущих тоже что и я.

Answer (score 0):

Чтож, заходите в настройки браузера, дальше ищите дополнения. В строке вбиваете расширение на латинице Стайлишь( не хочу чтобы забанили, так что сами переводите) а дальше вы сможете поменять тему на белую, серую или черную с синтаксом.

Поправка. Я гуглил, так что парой в расширениях вы можете не найти. Просто вбейте в браузере этот сайт, латиницей. Ключевые слова я подбирал как change theme color any website